# Parse simple CSV & get values with variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

This is probably a really simple thing to do, but I'm struggling. I've got a CSV file formatted like so;

```
"Afrojack","The Spark"
"All About She","Higher"
"Banks","This Is What It Feels Like"
"Bastille","Of The Night"
"Basto!","Gregory's Theme"
```

What I want to do is, load this data using PHP so that I can call the first and second items individually within a foreach loop. For example (the above data is an artist, and then a track name);

```
foreach (*this is also where I'm stuck*) {
    echo "Artist: $artist <br/>";
    echo "Track: $track <br />;
}
```

I'm not really a PHP guy, so I'd usually do this in javascript and use JSON, but in this instance it needs to be CSV and PHP :(

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only asked for a point in the right direction, here you go: [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply :) I have been trying that, but I can get it into an array, but from there it just baffles me. Perhaps I need more than just a pointer. :)

Comment: I've written a hopefully simple explanation about the working of the `for` and `foreach` loops: [here's the link](http://codepad.org/CCAelQzr).

Answer (score 0):

use `str_getcsv` — Parse a CSV string into an array

```
    $input ='csv data here';

    $datas = str_getcsv ($input, ',');

    foreach($datas as $key=>$value){

        echo "$key::$value";

    }
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is fine, but it returns the key as the key (e.g. [0], [1], [2] etc), when I need to be able to call (for example) $artist and $track against each row and it to return "Afrojack" and "the spark".

Comment: There is no mapping between artist and Afrojack, so instead of that. you can assume first key value is a artist, second key is track some thing like that

Comment: Yes, I get that. And that is initially what I tried to do. But it returns the following:
  0::Afrojack1::The Spark All About She2::Higher Banks3::This Is What It Feels Like Bastille4::Of The Night Basto!5::Gregory's Theme